# Take Photo and Get Bitmap&Uri - android

Tags: java, android

I have a web service which expects bitmap. `Choosing from gallery` option works well and uploads image to server, but I couldn't make it for `Take photo`

In both, I can set bitmap to my imageView before uploading (review). So, it gets bitmap and show in imageview but doesn't upload.
Do you have an idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance!
Here is my class;

```
public class TakePhoto extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button button, button2, button3;
private String encoded_string, image_name;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private File file;
private Uri file_uri;
private final int IMG_GALLERY = 1;
private final int IMG_CAMERA = 2;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == IMG_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri uri_gallery = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri_gallery);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(requestCode == IMG_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri uri_camera = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri_camera);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageShow);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void selectImage(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_GALLERY);

}

private void takeImage(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMG_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button:
            selectImage();
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            uploadImage();
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            takeImage();
            break;

    }


}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private void uploadImage(){

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("encoded_string",imageToString(bitmap));
    map.put("image_name","newimage");

    API_Service api_service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = api_service.sendImage(map);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Toast.makeText(TakePhoto.this, ""+response.body().getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(TakePhoto.this, "hata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed by compress my image, because it was 5MB+ and I think something went wrong about bytes.

Comment: Encoding large images to Base64 is not a good practice, they 'll be increased 31%-37% the file size. Your server will be overloaded.  I would advice to upload the byte array  with multipart/form-data POST request.